# Parameter that's a list of interface{}

Tags: go, interface

I'm trying to create a function that prints out the `len` of a list passed into it, regardless of the type of the list.  My naive way of doing this was:

```
func printLength(lis []interface{}) {
    fmt.Printf("Length: %d", len(lis))
}
```

However, when trying to use it via

```
func main() {
    strs := []string{"Hello,", "World!"}
    printLength(strs)
}
```

It complains saying

```
cannot use strs (type []string) as type []interface {} in argument to printLength
```

But, a `string` can be used as a `interface{}`, so why can't a `[]string` be used as a `[]interface{}`?

Comment: One of the go "special" things. There is no way to convert slice of one type to the other. You have to do it by hand in a `for` loop... As far as printing the length what you have done `fmt.Printf()` is the way.

Comment: Duplicate. See the Go FAQ: https://golang.org/doc/faq#convert_slice_of_interface

Answer (score 1):

You can use [reflect](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/) package - [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/GUDKkATrtGk)

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)
func printLength(lis interface{}) {
    fmt.Printf("Length: %d", reflect.ValueOf(lis).Len())
}
```